# Nested Loop is skipped within Function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, nested-loops, keydown

In a basic HTML/Javascript game, when moving my character I want to adjust AI movement so their speed/position is relative to the character's, not the canvas. My code works fine but only for whichever key's function is listed last.

```
//Left button
if (37 in keysDown) {
  if (robot.x <= 400) {

    //this for statement runs
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (boxes[1].x < 0) {
            boxes[i].x += robot.speed * modifier;
            robot.x = 400;

            //this for statement is the problem, doesn't run at all
            for (var j = 0; j < cogs.length; j++) {
                cogs[j].speedX = cogs[j].prevspeedX + robot.speed;
            }   
        };
     };
  };

  //this runs
  robot.x -= robot.speed * modifier;
} else {
  for (var j = 0; j < cogs.length; j++) {
      cogs[j].speedX = cogs[j].prevspeedX;
  }
};
```

And then the entire right button runs, because it comes after the left key:

```
//Right button
if (39 in keysDown) {
  if (robot.x >= canvas.width - 400) {
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (boxes[1].x > -3000 + canvas.width) {
            boxes[i].x -= robot.speed * modifier;
            robot.x = canvas.width - 400;

            //this is exactly identical to above, only robot.speed is subtracted
            for (var j = 0; j < cogs.length; j++) {
                cogs[j].speedX = cogs[j].prevspeedX - robot.speed;
            }
        }; 
    };
  };
  robot.x += robot.speed * modifier;
} else {
    for (var j = 0; j < cogs.length; j++) {
      cogs[j].speedX = cogs[j].prevspeedX;
    }
};
```

As far as I can tell this isn't an issue with any variables or values, because when I switch the order of right/left functions, the left begins working and the right stops.

Full Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqxbBX

EDIT: To clarify, the issue is not that my code doesn't work when I press the left arrow (37), the player and box movement portions are fine. (keysDown is an object not an array) **Only the section affecting cog movement** *when the player is moving left* **is not working**. The virtually identical code that runs when the right key is pressed works exactly as intended ... this is why it's been driving me mental.

I'll even take wild guesses at what may solve the issue!

Comment: Are you sure that you want to run this loop for each box?

Comment: Just tried moving the cogs loop outside the boxes loop for both right and left keys, but didn't change anything. Still works for only whichever key is listed second...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't exist in your `for` loops, but rather your `if else` structure.

You were close with your answer when you noticed that whatever was on bottom ran fine, but what was on top didn't. This was because if your top if statement was caught, the bottom else does which negates the movement of your cogs. Doing something like the following (which still has some bugs, mind you), will work:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGQPzw

One thing that I noticed as well is that if your robot runs into a wall, the cogs keep on speeding up even though the "box" itself isn't.

As an aside, it's also good form not to end your `if else` statements with semicolons since they're unnecessary.

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you for pointing that out, you're right that this fix is buggy but at least now that I know what the issue is I can work around it.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem are the conditions**

```
if (boxes[1].x < 0) {
```

**and**

```
if (boxes[1].x > -3000 + canvas.width) {
```

---

The floor's (`boxes[1]`) initial x value is `0`, hence it doesn't push through the if condition in the left button logic.

If you make it `if (boxes[1].x <= 0) {` and `if (boxes[1].x >= -3000 + canvas.width) {`, it should work fine.

The reason why putting the right button logic before the left button logic switches which one is working is because the right button logic changes the value of `boxes[1].x` so that it satisfies `boxes[1].x < 0`.

Comment: I just gave that a try and the cogs[j] loop is still not running for left key. Also tried moving the cogs loop outside of the boxes loop as Bergi suggested, so running the cogs loop is only dependent on 
`if (robot.x <= 400) {`